# How to dismiss DatePicker with selecting current date in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, datepicker, uidatepicker

Say I have the calendar picker show up with below code. Selecting a different date than current date would dismiss the picker. Selecting the current date (with blue background) will not. How to fix this?
[image]

```
@State private var testDate = Date()

DatePicker(
            "",
            selection: $testDate,
            displayedComponents: [.date]
)
.id(testDate)
```